# php chain method return variable and method calls another method

Tags: php, return-value, method-chaining

I saw different articles about chain method, but I still don't understand the difference between "return $this" and "return $this->SomeVariable".I also want to know how a method call another method within and without the class too.

Could someone kindly explain it ?
thanks you!

My example, it echo "bca", but I dont get why "a" is the last to display...

```
class validation {

    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
    public function one($a) {
        echo $a = "b";
        return $this;
    }
    public function two($a) {
        echo $a = "c";
        return $this->a;
    }
}

$a = "a";
$NameErr = new validation($a);
echo $NameErr->one($a)->two($a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is returned from *two($a)* since it returns *$this->a* that is set in constructor as *"a"*, and method *one($a)* returns instance of the object on which is then called function two.

$this refers to the object instance. So difference is that return $this->SomeVariable it just returns the variable.

Also just a nice coding tip. Declare $a in class as private variable like this:

```
 class Validation
 {
      private $a;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First let me say 
***$this*** refers to the class you are in.

This way of coding is called **fluent interface**. *return $this* returns the current object,

```
 $NameErr->one($a)->two($a);
```

is same as

```
$NameErr->one($a);
$NameErr->two($a);
```

And in this case

First the method ***one()*** is called,
  thus the value **b** is printed and the **object of the class is returned**.
 Now method ***two()*** is called,
 the value ***c*** is echoed out and the property is returned, which is echoed out side the class.

> ps: Declaring the variable $a as private would be a nice practice.